# Full Date pattern regex returning partial date patterns

Tags: php, regex, date

I have a regex

```
\d{1,2}(\.|–|-|\/|\s+)\d{1,2}(\.|–|-|\/|\s+)(\d{4}|\d{2})\b
```

I want it to return every pattern that has one or two digits followed by a space, period, slash, etc, followed by one or two digits followed by a space, period, slash, etc, followed by 4 or two digits.

For example 
08 18 78
18/8/1978
18/08/78
18 08 1978
18 8 78
18.8.1978
18.08.78
18/08/1978
18/8/78
08/1978
01.1978

and not 
08-78
08 78
11/12

However the regex is returning all of the above/

Here is my regex101
https://regex101.com/r/IQGyzD/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter your test strings one by one into the regex tester, you will see that 08-78 is not matched, and 08 78 11/12 is only partially matched as expected.

It seems with that with the regex101 tester you cannot enter multiple test strings at a time, in the way you are doing. :-)